# Reopening or bumping question on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

Some time ago, I've asked a question on Stack Overflow and haven't received an answer. I'm really interested in answers to my question. How can I reopen my question or bump it up in the queue without creating a new question with the same body?

Comment: Is your question closed or on hold? If not, see @juergend's link.

Answer (score 1):

You can throw a bounty on it. Which means you give a certain amount reputation to your question, so that the person with the right answer gets the reputation you have put on your question. You must have 75 reputation for it.

Comment: And if you edit the question it will be placed on the top of the "active" list